# Find Numeric Match, replace with delimited match. Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, enterprise

I'm working on searching for an occurrence of 1234567.0 and replacing all matches with 1234567 I'm using Enterprise wizard and can't understand why my regular expressions that work with visual studios won't work in the program.

Right now I'm trying `(/d{9})(/d{7})` I know I'm way off here and continue to dig into the cryptic world of regex.

Any regex wizards have a two cents in this. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite quite obviously a typo

Comment: @KenWhite It's funny. I like it there.

Comment: @KenWhite I *am* remaining helpful. Notice the answer. Was anyone negatively impacted by my comment? Is his regex going to break because I posted it? Is there any reason we can't have fun while helping people out? Smile a little. Life's better that way.

Comment: My "b" finger is faster than my "e" finger. ;)

Comment: @KenWhite A non-english speaker wouldn't generally say things like "dig into the cryptic world of regex" or have a name like "camdroid", I wouldn't suspect. If I had any doubt in my mind that it was a typo, I wouldn't have posted it.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Not sure I agree about the user name, but fair point about the rest. :-) I stand corrected in this case. Note the smiley? See, I do have a sense of humor. ;-) Deleting my comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d+\.\d+` will match 1 or more numbers, followed by a decimal, followed by one or more numbers.

If you want to capture the integer part, put parenthesis around it.

`(\d+)\.\d+`

---

`\d` is the special character for digit

`+` means "match at least one of these"

`\.` just matches a period. Since `.` is a special character, you have to escape it with a `\`

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - I saw your original answer - it was short. Then you realized my answer has a grouping, so in grace period you have updated your answer with that what you read in mine. Sure, why not. But next time when you do that, at least upvote your competitor for doing that... Good luck!

Comment: @Ωmega Or maaaaybe -- bear with me here, ok? Maybe I wrote my answer as quickly as possible so that it would be the first answer (as I often do), then reread the question (as I also often do), and was reminded that he'd like to replace and not just match, so I added a regex to do that. It's a fairly common-sense regex. I would bet that if you asked 100 developers to come up with a regex to do this, 99 of them would have used the same one we did. Don't get your panties in a wad.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - Nice try... You actually updated your answer more times and that grouping was added in your last update... But I don't mind :)

Comment: @Ωmega ...what? So? I update my answers all the time. What's that got to do with anything?

Comment: @Ωmega Lol, I don't understand what you're saying. Who cares if I updated it a hundred times and this was my last update? Still doesn't mean I took anything from you. You're failing to understand, *somehow*, that for this particular problem, the regex we used is trivial. Anyone would have used it. Thus, by extension, anyone who didn't have a complete answer at first would have added it to their answer upon realizing they needed it...Right? Dang, man. Chill. You have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - If that is so trivial, why you didn't put that to your answer on first time? Or at least in next edit? It is hard to believe you don't read others answers. Anyway, if you didn't understand my point, that answers a lot. I didn't ask you to respond to my very first comment and I didn't expect you will confess what you did... This conversation is over.

Comment: @Ωmega [lol](http://weknowmemes.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/watch-out-we-got-a-badass-over-here-meme.png)

Answer (score 1):

How about replace `(\d+)\.\d+` with first matching group..? That trims decimal part including period.

Comment: Can you give me an example, not quite sure I see the difference. Thank you for the response though.